# Get InlineImage in Specific Tables from Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I encountered the following problem. I have a Google Document, that contains a bunch of table objects and some of those tables contain inline images themselves.

With the `Body.getImages()` function I should be able to get the images of the whole document (right?). But is there any way to get the images from a specific table or is there a way to determine in which tables the images retrieved by the `Body.getImages()` method are located?

In case you are wondering what this is used for: My Google Doc is used to store several multiple-choice exam questions, where each question is represented by a table. I am trying to write a script to export these questions to a specific format and I encountered the problem that some of those questions contain images.

Comment: I think that providing your current script and the detail of issue of the script will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - `body.getImages()` will return an array of images.

We can use this array of images to find the corresponding table's for each image. If we use a recursive function on each image, we can `getParent()` up the document tree until the Parent Table to a particular image is found, then we list the element number (the `ChildIndex`) for the Table. If there is a "Question #" header in the table, we can search for it and return the question number of the located Table.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
      var body = doc.getBody();
      var tables = body.getTables();
      var images = doc.getBody().getImages();
      
      Logger.log("Found " + images.length + " images");
      Logger.log("Found " + tables.length + " tables");
      
      //list body element #'s for each tables
      let tableList = []
      tables.forEach(table => tableList.push(String(table.getParent().getChildIndex(table))))
      Logger.log("Tables at body element #s: ", tableList); 
      
      function findQuestionNumber (element, index) {
        parent = element.getParent() 
        //IF found the parent Table
        if (parent.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
          //Find the question # from the Table
          let range = parent.findText("Question")
          //Output where this image was found. (The childindex)
          Logger.log("found Image", String(index + 1), "in ", range.getElement().getParent().getText(), " at body element #", String(parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent)));
          return
          //use recursion to continue up the tree until the parent Table is found
        } else {
          findQuestionNumber(parent, index)
        }
      }
     
      //Run Function for each image in getImages() Array
      images.forEach((element, index) => findQuestionNumber(element, index));
      
    }
```

[image: Example Logs]

[image: Example Doc]

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I totally missed that there is a getParent() function! Your explanation was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
Unfortunately there are errors. Here it is:

11:11:16 PM Notice  Execution started
11:11:16 PM Info    Found 26 images
11:11:16 PM Info    Found 1 tables
11:11:16 PM Info    Tables at body element #s: 
11:11:17 PM Error   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of null
findQuestionNumber  @ Code.gs:22
findQuestionNumber  @ Code.gs:26
findQuestionNumber  @ Code.gs:26
findQuestionNumber  @ Code.gs:26
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:31
myFunction  @ Code.gs:31
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)